# Transaction Process - Deadlock Error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I'm facing the deadlock error when I update my data from software.

Here is my code:

```
private void btn_upd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constr);
        con.Open();
        string myquery = "Select Reg,Rank,Trade,Name,Wing,Father_name,Dob,Gender,Cast,Sect,Serial,Qualification,Tehseel,District,Cnic_No,Blood_Group,Height,Weight,Identification_Mark,Permanent_Add,Nameof_Spouse,Relation,Nameof_MaleKids,image1 from PersonalInfo where Reg='" + txt_srch.Text + "'";

        SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand(myquery, con);

        SqlDataReader rd = c.ExecuteReader();

        if (!(rd.HasRows))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No such data to delete");
        }
        else
        {
            string query;

            query = "update PersonalInfo set Rank='" + textBox2.Text + "', Serial='" + SN.Text + "', Trade='" + textBox3.Text + "',Name='" + textBox4.Text + "',Wing='" + textBox5.Text + "',Father_name='" + textBox6.Text + "',Dob='" + textBox7.Text + "',Gender='" + textBox8.Text + "',Cast='" + textBox9.Text + "',Sect='" + textBox23.Text + "',Qualification='" + textBox10.Text + "',Tehseel='" + textBox24.Text + "',District='" + textBox21.Text + "',Cnic_No='" + textBox11.Text + "',Blood_Group='" + textBox12.Text + "',Height='" + textBox13.Text + "',Weight='" + textBox14.Text + "',Identification_Mark='" + textBox15.Text + "',Permanent_Add='" + textBox16.Text + "',Nameof_Spouse='" + textBox18.Text + "',Relation='" + textBox19.Text + "',Nameof_MaleKids='" + textBox20.Text + "',image1='" + ImageToBase64(pictureBox1.Image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) + "' where Reg='" + txt_srch.Text + "'";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as marc_s already stated, concatenating your queries from direct user input is dangerous.  You should definitely consider changing that method and using paramterized queries, as suggested.

Second, try running each query within its own connection `Open()` and `Close()`:

```
private void btn_upd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constr);

        con.Open();

        string myquery = "Select Reg,Rank,Trade,Name,Wing,Father_name,Dob,Gender,Cast,Sect,Serial,Qualification,Tehseel,District,Cnic_No,Blood_Group,Height,Weight,Identification_Mark,Permanent_Add,Nameof_Spouse,Relation,Nameof_MaleKids,image1 from PersonalInfo where Reg='" + txt_srch.Text + "'";

        SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand(myquery, con);

        SqlDataReader rd = c.ExecuteReader();

        con.Close();

        if (!(rd.HasRows))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No such data to delete");
        }
        else
        {
            con.Open();

            string query;

            query = "update PersonalInfo set Rank='" + textBox2.Text + "', Serial='" + SN.Text + "', Trade='" + textBox3.Text + "',Name='" + textBox4.Text + "',Wing='" + textBox5.Text + "',Father_name='" + textBox6.Text + "',Dob='" + textBox7.Text + "',Gender='" + textBox8.Text + "',Cast='" + textBox9.Text + "',Sect='" + textBox23.Text + "',Qualification='" + textBox10.Text + "',Tehseel='" + textBox24.Text + "',District='" + textBox21.Text + "',Cnic_No='" + textBox11.Text + "',Blood_Group='" + textBox12.Text + "',Height='" + textBox13.Text + "',Weight='" + textBox14.Text + "',Identification_Mark='" + textBox15.Text + "',Permanent_Add='" + textBox16.Text + "',Nameof_Spouse='" + textBox18.Text + "',Relation='" + textBox19.Text + "',Nameof_MaleKids='" + textBox20.Text + "',image1='" + ImageToBase64(pictureBox1.Image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) + "' where Reg='" + txt_srch.Text + "'";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this would be correct. Beat me to it! @Syed You cannot do multiple SQL commands inside the ONE cmd object unless you joind the SQL together as part of a transaction, a stored procedure, or a function.